# Sorting all connected components by area and exporting them fails, how to resolve this?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

Given an image of 200 blobs, I'd like to retrieve the 10 largest blobs:

So I have used **connectedComponentsWithStats** function, and sorted the stats by their area (**CC_STAT_AREA**). but it seems the stats were sorted and the corresponding labels lost their match:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, labels, stats, _ = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(gray, connectivity=4)
indexes_group = np.argsort(stats[:, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA])
stats = stats[indexes_group]

for component_id, stat in enumerate(stats):
    single_component = (labels == component_id).astype(np.uint8) * 255
    cv2.imwrite("blob" +str(component_id)r+".png",single_component)
```

I know that each pixel has the value of its label, and all 0 's represent the background, i.e: [image]

Can someone please explain me more in depth what steps should I take for fixing my code?

Thank you!

Comment: The row number is what associates each set of statistics with a label. Obviously if you shuffle the rows around, you break this association. Either do an indirect sort (just sorting the indices), or transform the data you sort such that it also contains the original index (i.e. label) -- e.g. add a column..

Comment: @Dan Mašek can you please give me an example. cause the solution is not yet clear for me. 
thank you

Comment: Actually, after closer look, you're already using indirect sort. `indexes_group` is basically sorted list of labels. I think if you replace `enumerate(stats)` with `zip(indexes_group, stats)`, it ought to work as you want.

Comment: Thank you @DanMašek!! :) worked like a charm!